# How to set element fixed horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clone Netflix carousel.
I am not able to set the header fixed when I scroll horizontally the sections.

The sections and header overlap eachother, but the first ones should stay at the bottom of the page.
is there an easy way to do it?

```
<div class="headerwrapper">
  <header> // here I put nav, an iframe video as in Netflix and same text to describe the movie. The header is already set with position relative because I needed to cut of some text from the top of the video (video taken from youtube)

  </header>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <section> </section>  // inside each sections there are 6 images. the sections are flexed and take 100%
  <section> </section>
  <section> </section>
</div>

.headerwrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the height of the .headerwrapper you should be able to do it like this:

```
.headerwrapper {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headerwrapper:nth-child(2) {
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I need it fixed only when I scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want it to scroll horizontally forget position fixed, each image should be something like this:

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

and the container for them should say "overflow-x: scroll". This way it won't be fixed but can scroll left and right